Can anyone teach me how to check if a sequence is monotonic
I was reading a book calculus by tarasov.
In there was a question to check if $y_n=n^2-3n$ was monotonic
I checked it using the derivative method but fount out the although $y=x^2-3x$ wasn't monotonic; $y_n=n^2-3n$ was nondecreasing...
Which means that the derivative method (checking if $\frac{dy}{dx} = 0$ ) doesn't work for numerical sequences... Can anyone tell me a foolproof method to help me check if a sequence is monotonic??

Monotone means "increasing" or "decreasing." The most elementary way to do this is with inequalities. Hint: if $i < j$, can you compare $i^2$ and $j^2$?

$y_{n+1} - y_{n} > 0$

As a general matter, discrete numerical problems can be harder than continuous ones.  Optimization, say...the fact that the continuous max occurs at, say, $1.5$ does not prove that the discrete max occurs at $1$ or $2$.  There is no "foolproof" method that always works.

You have $y_0=0$, $y_1=-2$, $y_2=-1$, $y_3=3$. So it's important to say what is the range of $n$.

So the derivative method for checking for monotonic increase says that you only have to check $y_k < y_{k+1}$ if $y_k = f(k)$ is a differentiable function and its derivative goes negative between $k$ and $k+1$ (or if it stays 0 almost everywhere along the interval as kind of a degenerate case). If the derivative is nonnegative between $k$ and $k+1$ then its integral increases between them.
You take a derivative of $x^2 - 3x$, that's $2x-3$, which is negative at x=0, x=1, but turns positive before x=2. As a result we know that we have monotonic increase for $n > 2$ but we have to check (0, 1, 2) manually. And when we check those we find $\{0, -2, -2, 0, 4, \dots\}$. We know that from $y_2=-2$ to $y_3=0$ to $y_4=4$ and on up, the sequence will be monotonically increasing by the derivative method.
So we see that it's monotonically increasing for $n > 2$ but between $n=1$ and $n=2$ it is stationary and between $n=0$ and $n=1$ it is actually decreasing. (Indeed, monotonically decreasing for $n < 1.$) Whether the sequence is "monotonic" then depends on where you are taking the sequence to start or end.

No such thing is possible. Sequences aren’t algebraic expressions like $n^2 - 3n$.
Facetious example: I could say let $x_n = n$ except set $x_7 = 0$ iff the Riemann hypothesis is true. Now the only way to ‘check’ if the sequence is monotonic is to solve the Riemann hypothesis.
